# how to show the game start page in centre

Tags: java, android

I think my question is quit easy,so thanks for your help.I have made a simple game ,finally run ,but I can't make the start content show in center of the page,could anyone help me out of this?

this is present page:

please enter here to see the [rendering](http://img.my.csdn.net/uploads/201212/05/1354694765_6594.jpg)
code:

res/layout/activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="#7ba6df"
                android:text="@string/activity_main_title"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/continue_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/continue_lable"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/new_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/new_game_lable"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/about_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/about_lable"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exit_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/exit_lable"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

res/values/string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="activity_main_title">android sudoku</string>
    <string name="continue_lable">开始游戏</string>
    <string name="about_lable">游戏说明</string>
    <string name="new_game_lable">是否开启音乐</string>
    <string name="exit_lable">退出游戏</string>

</resources>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: apply layout_gravity = center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_title"
            android:textColor="#7ba6df"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continue_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/continue_lable" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/new_game_lable" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/about_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/about_lable" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/exit_lable" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified **xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="#7ba6df"
                android:text="@string/activity_main_title"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/continue_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/continue_lable"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/new_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/new_game_lable"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/about_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/about_lable"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exit_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/exit_lable"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Three options you can add to the layout code

1.

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

2.

```
android:centerInParent="true"
```

3.

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```